# How to get original User Control Name?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have created an User Control with these parameters

```
 private System.Resources.ResourceSet ProjectRes = Магазин.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), true, true);
    public ButtonPictureBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap Imagen = (Bitmap)ProjectRes.GetObject((sender as PictureBox).Name.Substring(2) + "1");
        if (Imagen != null)
        {
            (sender as PictureBox).Image = Imagen;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap Imagen = (Bitmap)ProjectRes.GetObject((sender as PictureBox).Name.Substring(2) + "2");
        if (Imagen != null)
        {
            (sender as PictureBox).Image = Imagen;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap Imagen = (Bitmap)ProjectRes.GetObject((sender as PictureBox).Name.Substring(2) + "1");
        if (Imagen != null)
        {
            (sender as PictureBox).Image = Imagen;
        }
    }
```

When i use it in a form, i NAME the created UserControl but that name seems to not pass to those functions, how can i make it inherit the name?

Comment: You shared half of the story. share complete code for user control and the form where you tried to use. also point out where what you tried to do and what happened.

Comment: Used that user control in a form. Named the control as "toys" ran the project, sender.name is picturebox1 in user control code instead of the name "toys" that I need

Answer (score 0):

```
base.Name
```

Was what i was looking for. Used it instead of `(sender as PictureBox).Name` and it started working